# INDEXER Lake Framework - outcome.status.failure not showing execution error

Tags: nearprotocol, indexer

The following transaction
https://explorer.near.org/transactions/CkZYiXB3BEoXNuLDqcn5GjErkXghKGCB47yPyyze4kTf#BPYU8T3o5mdsU4ewG3JdCLRe8ivpsGTehKxkifFAsboD

failed whith the following error:

```
{
  "type": "action",
  "error": {
    "type": "functionCallError",
    "error": {
      "type": "executionError",
      "error": "Smart contract panicked: The contract is not initialized"
    }
  }
}
```

But what I got on the indexer is the following:

```
{
   "outcome":{
      "executionOutcome":{
         "blockHash":"8NP4Z2i7CBQzRUxa8CfuummnYZvwfZaCFmif4d6mcgyB",
         "id":"CkZYiXB3BEoXNuLDqcn5GjErkXghKGCB47yPyyze4kTf",
         "outcome":{
            "executorId":"test1.csandi.near",
            "gasBurnt":2428211671420,
            "logs":[
               
            ],
            "metadata":{
               "gasProfile":null,
               "version":1
            },
            "receiptIds":[
               "GrXdFKA9byvCmxGiQkGc9iaFn88FfePk4tfJhvcTGMwc"
            ],
            "status":{
               "SuccessReceiptId":"GrXdFKA9byvCmxGiQkGc9iaFn88FfePk4tfJhvcTGMwc"
            },
            "tokensBurnt":"242821167142000000000"
         },
         "proof":[
            {
               "direction":"Left",
               "hash":"BWhmGBmvzbX3WBP1RZQ59DB749sHSV2xS5pNyF6xAbbh"
            },
            {
               "direction":"Right",
               "hash":"H4YMDcd9Fh68KTwyPTwYuFb89KhfdGUoxRbBYzDcNAze"
            },
            {
               "direction":"Right",
               "hash":"9jv152euKvurdVkDYS5FKiiT4ej6xL1gRYTHoNbjwEZi"
            },
            {
               "direction":"Right",
               "hash":"BqQFHzSYzqDE8tMQkJT8PHFGxLmQrkFBcuTqFP4nTjx7"
            }
         ]
      },
      "receipt":null
   },
   "transaction":{
      "actions":[
         {
            "FunctionCall":{
               "args":"eyJpbml0aWFsX3ByaWNlIjoxLjksInNwYWNpbmciOjIsImFscGhhX2lkIjoidXNuIiwiYmV0YV9pZCI6IndyYXAubmVhciIsInN3YXBfZmVlX3JhdGUiOjAuMDAzLCJwcm90b2NvbF90b2xsIjowLjAxfQ==",
               "deposit":"0",
               "gas":200000000000000,
               "methodName":"create_new_pool"
            }
         }
      ],
      "hash":"CkZYiXB3BEoXNuLDqcn5GjErkXghKGCB47yPyyze4kTf",
      "nonce":75627675000007,
      "publicKey":"ed25519:85yAx5mY8DinTWQfMn47cZTHMhZtLRAWZLpazYmetwno",
      "receiverId":"dev-cliquidity-perk-jorge.near",
      "signature":"ed25519:1CieS8AUSc7Y3S8By8adJaEXXydXcjvSA1uVXPgrdhkmGPpf5ykA7XWqJGZnDhMtymkp6eWDBEQzsBXkhybAbUV",
      "signerId":"test1.csandi.near"
   }
}
```

So I would like to know if there is anyway to get the failure message from the indexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the next blocks for the corresponding receipt from the `SuccessReceiptId` (id  `GrXdFKA9byvCmxGiQkGc9iaFn88FfePk4tfJhvcTGMwc`), and in its execution outcome you will find that status.

I cannot recommend more to watch or read the [Data Flow in NEAR](https://near-indexers.io/docs/data-flow-and-structures/flow/near-data-flow)

Comment: Thank you, that definitely clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, just to follow up and clarify for anyone with this question, after following the above response by "Vlad Frolov", in order to get the Receipt Status, I had to check

`shard.receiptExecutionOutcomes`

which will provide the results of the receipts, so I started to track the receipts that I am interested in, in this case for
`SuccessReceiptId (GrXdFKA9byvCmxGiQkGc9iaFn88FfePk4tfJhvcTGMwc)`

> ```
> "executionOutcome":{
>    "blockHash":"59F5pES9Myc2VT4JkppE95epCwtGAXYux9okbzpsh95K",
>    "id":"**GrXdFKA9byvCmxGiQkGc9iaFn88FfePk4tfJhvcTGMwc**",
>    "outcome":{
>      "executorId":"dev-cliquidity-perk-jorge.near",
>      "gasBurnt":2824274578054,
>      "logs":[
>         
>      ],
>      "metadata":{
>         "gasProfile":[
>            {
>               "cost":"BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"1323840555"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"CONTRACT_LOADING_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"35445963"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"CONTRACT_LOADING_BYTES",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"106584645000"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"READ_MEMORY_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"5219726400"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"READ_MEMORY_BYTE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"136847988"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"READ_REGISTER_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"2517165186"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"READ_REGISTER_BYTE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"11334630"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"STORAGE_READ_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"56356845750"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"STORAGE_READ_KEY_BYTE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"154762665"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"TOUCHING_TRIE_NODE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"193223471112"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"UTF8_DECODING_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"3111779061"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"UTF8_DECODING_BYTE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"9038994849"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"WASM_INSTRUCTION",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"11928316488"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"WRITE_MEMORY_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"2803794861"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"WRITE_MEMORY_BYTE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"313233780"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"WRITE_REGISTER_BASE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"2865522486"
>            },
>            {
>               "cost":"WRITE_REGISTER_BYTE",
>               "costCategory":"WASM_HOST_COST",
>               "gasUsed":"437179860"
>            }
>         ],
>         "version":1
>      },
>      "receiptIds":[
>         "BPYU8T3o5mdsU4ewG3JdCLRe8ivpsGTehKxkifFAsboD"
>      ],
>      **"status":{
>         "Failure":{
>            "ActionError":{
>               "index":0,
>               "kind":{
>                  "FunctionCallError":{
>                     "ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: The contract is not initialized"
>                  }
>               }
>            }
>         }**
>      },
>      "tokensBurnt":"282427457805400000000"
>   },
>   "proof":[
>      {
>         "direction":"Left",
>         "hash":"5j1RhLnf5jGChUPxU9CPNbAGwSn6VnzBw7taJe5vSnYD"
>      },
>      {
>         "direction":"Right",
>         "hash":"AJ2kARUcYAkzsL3xmw4jAETZ61jtQuswf7RvhSxscKCR"
>      },
>      {
>         "direction":"Left",
>         "hash":"9vXQjFdTaQw5XjUKsRK6N3WFCg5zMVca5Ze2Qqznn3AM"
>      }
>   ]    },    "receipt":{
>   "predecessorId":"test1.csandi.near",
>   "receipt":{
>      "Action":{
>         "actions":[
>            {
>               "FunctionCall":{
>                  "args":"eyJpbml0aWFsX3ByaWNlIjoxLjksInNwYWNpbmciOjIsImFscGhhX2lkIjoidXNuIiwiYmV0YV9pZCI6IndyYXAubmVhciIsInN3YXBfZmVlX3JhdGUiOjAuMDAzLCJwcm90b2NvbF90b2xsIjowLjAxfQ==",
>                  "deposit":"0",
>                  "gas":200000000000000,
>                  "methodName":"create_new_pool"
>               }
>            }
>         ],
>         "gasPrice":"346069590",
>         "inputDataIds":[
>            
>         ],
>         "outputDataReceivers":[
>            
>         ],
>         "signerId":"test1.csandi.near",
>         "signerPublicKey":"ed25519:85yAx5mY8DinTWQfMn47cZTHMhZtLRAWZLpazYmetwno"
>      }
>   },
>   "receiptId":"GrXdFKA9byvCmxGiQkGc9iaFn88FfePk4tfJhvcTGMwc",
>   "receiverId":"dev-cliquidity-perk-jorge.near"    } }
> ```

And as you can see in the json response,the following status:

```
"status":{
        "Failure":{
           "ActionError":{
              "index":0,
              "kind":{
                 "FunctionCallError":{
                    "ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: The contract is not initialized"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

Anyway to fully understand how transactions/receipts work [this document](https://nomicon.io/RuntimeSpec/Receipts) helped a lot.